# Is the RxJS map operator used only for (x=>x) the wrong operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

So in vanilla JS I the way I understand the map operator is that it iterates through every item in an array and does work on that item. So if I have an array:

```
 [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
```

Then .map would iterate over each object in this array, exposing that object's properties while you're inside of it.

With RxJS I most commonly see this: `map(x=>x).map(...)` because it seems the RxJS map operator **doesn't actually** iterate over each object in the array. I see that it's most commonly used simple to expose the inside of the observable so that other work can be done on it.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a more semantic operator for map(x=>x)?
2. Why does RxJS's map deviate from Javascript's map?

Comment: `array.map` applies the function to each value in the array. `observable.map` applies the function to each value *in the stream*. It's not clear why you think this isn't doing the same thing; a map over an array of arrays doesn't unroll the inner arrays.

Comment: thanks you addressed the gap in my knowledge @jonrsharpe

Comment: Also, map(x=>x) doesn't do anything, whether the receiver is an array or an Observable.

Comment: pipe(map(x=>x)) is the correct approach, the .map syntax is deprecated

Comment: @danday74 I meant using JS's Array.map on the results of the Observable, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

An array is a list in memory.

An Obserable stream is a list over time.

Since they are essentially both just lists, it makes sense that they have very similar methods. In fact, most array methods exist on a stream.

See the docs to illustrate this:

https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables#observables-compared-to-arrays

So yes, map on a stream does pretty much the same as map on an array.